# How to allow user formatting in React app?

Tags: reactjs, formatting, user-input

I have a React app where a user can type something into textbox, click 'submit' and then the text appears somewhere.

I want to add functionality which will allow the user to format the text. Just like you can do here on SE when asking questions. For example I want the below input to be shown as **bold**.

```
<b>bold</b>
```

How can I achieve this? Or where to look for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable the same functionality you get in stack overflow, then I think the one way to achieve this would be allowing the user to input markdown and converting that to HTML. This is a library that could help with that: [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked)

Freecodecamp has a markdown previewer as one of their projects, so if you want to check out some examples, you could probably find hundreds of different implementations: https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/build-a-markdown-previewer/198715

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. react-markdown works perfectly for me. Do you know about any easy way to combine it with Latex?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done using state, as well as a checkbox toggle to determine whether or not the text should be bold or not.

`handleChange` will update the input. `handleFormatChange` will update whether or not you should use bold text or not. In the `render`, a conditional can be implemented to determine when to render what format.

```js
class Formatter extends React.Component {

  state = {
    format: false,
    input: ""
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleFormatChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      format: !this.state.format
    })
  }

  render() {
    var input = this.state.format 
    ? <b> {this.state.input} </b> 
    : <p> {this.state.input} </p>

    return ( 
      <div>
         Bold <input type="checkbox"
                     onChange = {
                       this.handleFormatChange
                     }
              />
              <br />
              <input value={this.state.input}
                     onChange = {this.handleChange}
              /> 
              <br/>
              {input} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( <
  Formatter / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```